# Inverse Discrete Time Fourier Transform of spectrometer data in python

Tags: python, fft, spectrum

So I have been trying to automate the conversion of my pulsed laser spectrum data to pulse duration via a python script. However somehow my transformed data does not seem to fit. Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Inverse Discrete Time Fourier Transformation
def IDTFT(N,intensity,frequency,time):
    inverse = np.zeros(len(time),dtype=np.clongdouble)
    for t in range(len(time)):
        for k in range(N):
            inverse[t] += (1/N)*intensity[k]*np.exp((1j*2*np.pi*frequency[k]*time[t])/N)
    return inverse

# Load Data
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\lukas\Downloads\Data.txt',sep='\t')

# Extract quantities
intensity = df['Intensity']
wavelength = df['Wavelength']
frequency = 299792458/(wavelength*1e-9)
time = np.arange(0,2024e-15,1e-15)

# Plot frequency domain
plt.figure(0)
plt.grid()
plt.plot(frequency,intensity,'o')
plt.show()
```

Frequency Domain (xaxis=[Hz]):

[image]

```
# Transform 
inverse = IDTFT(len(wavelength),intensity,frequency,time)

# Plot time domain
plt.figure(1)
plt.grid()
plt.plot(time,inverse,'o')
plt.show()
```

Time domain (xaxis = [s]):

[image]

Comment: Hello, please explain how the results you are getting are not what you expect. Also, consider using numpy fft module for the forward and inverse Fourier transforms, instead of rewriting the functionality from scratch on your own. Going through the documentation of the module may help you clarify things.

Comment: I know that this pulse should be around 60 fs. However if I use my transformed data I get a pulse duration of around 400 ps. I will try to use the numpy fft module, maybe that will help. Thank you!